# Pandas: convert to time series with frequency counts + maintaining index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I currently have pandas df that looks like:

```
Company Date        Title
Apple   1/2/2020    Sr. Exec
Google  2/2/2020    Manager
Google  2/2/2020    Analyst
```

How do I get it to maintain the index while counting the frequency of 'title' per date (as shown below)

```
    Company  1/2/2020   2/2/2020
     Apple   1          0
     Google  0          2
```

I've tried using group_by() on the date but it doesn't break up the dates to show on the top row and I need to export the resulting df to csv so group by didn't work.

Comment: `df.groupby('Company')['Date'].value_counts().unstack('Date', fill_value=0)`

Comment: upvoted Quang Hoang because it works. Now trying to figure out how! :)

Comment: I just did, and IMHO it's the best answer

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
pd.pivot_table(df, index='Company', columns='Date', values='Title', aggfunc='count').reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1).fillna(0)
```

**Output:**

```
  Company  1/2/2020  2/2/2020
0   Apple       1.0       0.0
1  Google       0.0       2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you want is a pivot table

```
pivot = df.pivot_table(
    index="Company",
    columns="Date",
    values="Title",
    aggfunc=len,
    fill_value=0
).reset_index()
```

A quick explanation of what is happening here:

1. Rows will be made for each unique value in the 'Company' column
2. Values from the 'Date' column will become column headers
3. We want to count how frequently a title occurs at a given date in a given company, so we set the 'Title' to be the value and pass the aggfunc (aggregation function) of len to tell pandas to count the values
4. Since there could be an instance where Google doesn't have any analysts on the 20th of Febuary 2020 we supply a fill_value of 0, preventing empty (Null) values
5. Finally, we reset the index so that the 'Company' value is just a column not the index of the dataframe.

You will end up having a new index, but this is inevitable since you are no longer going to have rows with duplicated values in the 'Company' column.

The pivot_table method is extremely powerful.  Look [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) for the full documentation